# Python Bottle Website Automate Tasks

Tags: python-2.7, bottle

I have a python app that pulls data and posts it into an API. It pulls data from the last 15 minutes and needs to run every 15 minutes.

I ended up using the bottle framework and running my code in the background of a page and refreshing it every 15 minutes (which I'm assuming isn't the best way to do this).

```
@route('/')
def index():

    <run code>

    return '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900" />'
```

How do I automate this task, while having a user friendly way to turn this off and on that isn't dependent on having a browser open?

Answer (score 1):

If all I wanted to do was pull data and post it to an API every 15 minutes, I wouldn't use a web framework. I would write a script with an infinite while loop and use sleep(). Of course you can bind this script/function to a bottle URL if you wanted to.

Edit (Missed some of OP's requirements): If the want the user to be able to select a date, make a form where the user can submit a date. Your bottle backend would then spawn a new process (python script) which takes the submitted date as input. This process would continuously run your code until say your user hits an 'end' button and then your bottle backend would kill the process. See [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more information on spawning/deleting processes.

Comment: I also need to allow users to manually enter in dates to pull data from, which is why I'm using a web framework.

Comment: @AllenLin - I think that a Thread/ThreadPool would be much more easy to handle in this case so you won't have zombie processing on each bottle reload...